# Use a list as pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to find out if any item of my list matches user input. 
Can I use regex?

```py
Inp = input()
Lis = ['banana','Orange', 'apple']
```

In reality, my list has more than 50 objects. So I can't use ('banana'| 'apple'|...) method.
And `x for x in lis` only makes a generator.

EDIT:
I wanna return all matches. Like example below:

```py
Inp = 'abbc'
Lis =['b','c']
Output = bbc
```

EDIT2: 
I found the answer. But it still use a while loop:

```py
string  = "abbc"
pattern = ['b','c']
new =[]
counter = 0
while True:
    if counter <= len (pattern)-1:
        find = re.findall(pattern[counter], string)
        counter += 1
        new.extend(find)
        continue
    else:
        break
print(new) 
#this will return ['b','b','c']
```

Comment: `if Inp in Lis:`. That way you can check your input against an entire list without using multiple if conditions.

Comment: What If inp= "abanana" and I want output like "banana"?

Comment: Then you'll have to use a loop.

Comment: @Neu can you update your answer with exactly *how* you want your filter to work?  Both answers provided seem reasonable but it looks like they aren't what you are looking for.

Comment: Yup! Seems my question wasn't clear. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use a regex for this, you can use something like this:

```
for x in List:
    if x in Inp:
        ...
```

But if you want to use a regex, you obviously can:

```
re.find('|'.join(Lis), Inp)
```

Comment: Thanks! But if inp=nnp and lis=['n','p'] it will return only 'n' and 'p'

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`filter`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#filter) to find all occurences that match with your input string:

```
Inp = input()
Lis = ['banana','Orange', 'apple']

result = list(filter(lambda item: Inp.find(item) != -1, Lis))
```

Comment: Thanks but This won't work if inp= bbc and lis = ['b','c']

Comment: I even copied your answer but it's still returning b and c :(.(I think you're misunderstanding my question. I wanna return bbc if inp = "abbc" and lis =['b','c']

Comment: @Francisco Couzo Any suggestions? Please read edited paragraph in my question.